# Split XML file in C# and keep the outer nodes

Tags: c#, xml, split

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<root>
<elements>
    <element>
        <value1>a</value1>
        <value2>b</value2>
    </element>
    <element>
        <value1>c</value1>
        <value2>d</value2>
    </element>
    <element>
        <value1>e</value1>
        <value2>f</value2>
    </element>
    <element>
        <value1>g</value1>
        <value2>h</value2>
    </element>
</elements>
<return>0</return></root>
```

And I want to split it into x files that look like this:
e.g.

```
<root>
<elements>
    <element>
        <value1>a</value1>
        <value2>b</value2>
    </element>
    <element>
        <value1>c</value1>
        <value2>d</value2>
    </element>
</elements>
<return>0</return></root>
```

The code I am using is really ugly and not generic at all.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XMLSplit2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath, file, outputFolder;
            XDocument xml;

            file = @"test.xml";
            outputFolder = @"C:\test\out\";
            filePath = @"C:\test\in\" + file;

            string _Header = @"<root><elements>";
            string _Footer = @"</elements><return>0</return></root>";
            int _BatchSize = 2;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;


            xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);
            XElement element = xml.Root.Elements().ElementAt(0);
            var xdoc = new XDocument(element);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


            string newXml = "";
            sb.Append(_Header);
            XElement last = xdoc.Root.Elements().Last();


            foreach (XElement singleElement in xdoc.Root.Elements())
            {
                i++;
                sb.Append(singleElement.ToString());
                if (i % _BatchSize == 0 || singleElement.Equals(last))
                {
                    j++;
                    sb.Append(_Footer);
                    newXml = sb.ToString();
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outputFolder + j.ToString() + "_" + file, newXml);

                    sb.Clear();
                    sb.Append(_Header);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

What I want to get rid of the variables _Header and _Footer. What do I have to do to keep the border and fill it with x element-nodes? Or is it impossible to do without xslt?

Comment: So, from the original XML file you need to produce an XML file that contains half of `<element>`, only elements with values `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, all elements not equal to `e`, `f`, `g`, `h`, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building up an XML file using string concatenation should generally be avoided. It is much simpler when `Linq-to-XML` is used:

```
 // use this namespace
 using System.Xml.Linq;

 // Create 'footer' and 'header' elements
 XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
 XElement xElm = new XElement("root",
                    new XElement("elements"),
                    new XElement("return", 0)                                    
                 );
 xmlDoc.Add(xElm);
```

to produce:

```
- <root>
  <elements /> 
  <return>0</return> 
  </root>
```

You can now easily add any nodes you want from the original XML file:

```
// Load XML file
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\mypath\mydoc.xml");
// Take the first two <element>s and add them to the new XML being produced
foreach (XElement elm in doc.Descendants("element").Take(2))
{
   xmlDoc.Root.Element("elements").Add(new XElement(elm));
}
```

to get the required result:

```
- <root>
- <elements>
   - <element>
        <value1>a</value1> 
        <value2>b</value2> 
     </element>
   - <element>
        <value1>c</value1> 
        <value2>d</value2> 
     </element>
  </elements>
  <return>0</return> 
  </root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below solution to achieve what you intend to.

```
        try
        {
            var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            string file = "input.xml";
            int batchSize = 2;
            if(File.Exists(file))
            {
                xDoc.Load(file);

                var elements = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/root/elements/element");
                if(elements!=null && elements.Count>batchSize)
                {
                    var elementsToRetain = elements.OfType<XmlNode>().Take(batchSize);
                    var elementsNode = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/root/elements");
                    elementsNode.RemoveAll();

                    foreach(var ele in elementsToRetain)
                    {
                        elementsNode.AppendChild(ele);
                    }
                }
                xDoc.Save("output.xml");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```